# Structure module reordering

Tags: ee3, structure, eeharbor

I'm having issues with the Structure module. When I reorder pages from backend, it gives me error in console.

> {"success":false,"errors":"Reordering Failed\n\nYour Structure Tree
>   appears to be out of date.\n\nSomeone else may be editing or you may
>   have another tab with a newer Structure tree.\n\nPlease refresh and
>   try reordering again."}

Here is the screenshots:

1. Normal pages at structure backend:

[image]

2. Alert error message by Structure module:

[image]

3. Console error of the plugin:

[image]

Please help me out with this. **My EE version is 3.5.6 and Structure version is 4.1.12**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"**Updated**" column shouldn't be `NULL` or `empty` or `0`. It must contain a date to start reordering.
Sometimes it not set at default install of structure and that cause this error.

Update the first row's "updated" column in DB with date will solve the issue.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`Updated` column in `exp_structure` table should not be `NULL`.

Use this SQL script to fix reordering issue:

`UPDATE exp_structure
SET updated = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
WHERE entry_id = 0;`